# Parser Json volley request

Tags: android, json

Veran, tengo un Json que me funciona correctamente siendo este:

```
   {
    "codCompeticion": "284",
    "nomCompeticion": "2Âª.Cadete I \"Copa Coca Cola\" Valencia",
    "jornadas": [
      {
        "jornada": "1",
        "idClubLocal": "0201211",
        "idEquipoLocal": "0201211301",
        "nomLocal": "Meliana C.F. \"A\"",
        "idClubVisitante": "0201045",
        "idEquipoVisitante": "0201045301",
        "nomVisitante": "RafelbuÃ±ol C.F.",
        "resLocal": "0",
        "resVisitante": "3",
        "fecha": "17/10/2015",
        "hora": "10:30",
        "codInfo": "81769",
        "escudoLocal": "./img/logosClubes/0201211.jpg",
        "escudoVisitante": "./img/logosClubes/0201045.jpg"
      },
      {
        "jornada": "2",
        "idClubLocal": "0201045",
        "idEquipoLocal": "0201045301",
        "nomLocal": "RafelbuÃ±ol C.F.",
        "idClubVisitante": "0201573",
        "idEquipoVisitante": "0201573211",
        "nomVisitante": "F.B. Alfara Del Patriarca",
        "resLocal": "0",
        "resVisitante": "10",
        "fecha": "24/10/2015",
        "hora": "12:30",
        "codInfo": "123322",
        "escudoLocal": "./img/logosClubes/0201045.jpg",
        "escudoVisitante": "./img/logosClubes/0201573.jpg"

      }
    ]
  }
```

Y este es el codigo para parsearlo:

```
public List<Calendario_Volley> parseJson(JSONObject jsonObject){
    // Variables locales
    List<Calendario_Volley> rankingAmonestacionesCadetes = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONArray jsonArray= null;

    try {
        // Obtener el array del objeto
        jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("jornadas");

        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){

            try {
                JSONObject objeto= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Calendario_Volley RankingAmonestacionesCadetes = new Calendario_Volley(
                        ("JORNADA - ")+objeto.getString("jornada"),
                        ("FECHA - ")+objeto.getString("fecha"),
                        objeto.getString("nomLocal"),
                        ("HORA - ")+objeto.getString("hora"),
                        objeto.getString("nomVisitante"),
                        objeto.getString("resVisitante"),
                        objeto.getString("resLocal")+(" - "),
                        ("ARBITRO - ")+objeto.getString("arbitro"),

                        objeto.getString("escudoLocal"),
                        objeto.getString("escudoVisitante")+(" - "));
```

Pero, ¿como se hace para parsearlo si empieza en corchete?

```
[
  {
    "codCompeticion": "284",
    "nomCompeticion": "2Âª.Cadete I \"Copa Coca Cola\" Valencia",
    "jornadas": [
      {
        "jornada": "1",
        "idClubLocal": "0201211",
        "idEquipoLocal": "0201211301",
        "nomLocal": "Meliana C.F. \"A\"",
        "idClubVisitante": "0201045",
        "idEquipoVisitante": "0201045301",
        "nomVisitante": "RafelbuÃ±ol C.F.",
        "resLocal": "0",
        "resVisitante": "3",
        "fecha": "17/10/2015",
        "hora": "10:30",
        "codInfo": "81769",
        "escudoLocal": "./img/logosClubes/0201211.jpg",
        "escudoVisitante": "./img/logosClubes/0201045.jpg"
      },
      {
        "jornada": "2",
        "idClubLocal": "0201045",
        "idEquipoLocal": "0201045301",
        "nomLocal": "RafelbuÃ±ol C.F.",
        "idClubVisitante": "0201573",
        "idEquipoVisitante": "0201573211",
        "nomVisitante": "F.B. Alfara Del Patriarca",
        "resLocal": "0",
        "resVisitante": "10",
        "fecha": "24/10/2015",
        "hora": "12:30",
        "codInfo": "123322",
        "escudoLocal": "./img/logosClubes/0201045.jpg",
        "escudoVisitante": "./img/logosClubes/0201573.jpg"

      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta y adecua tu código a obtener un JsonArray, obtener los objetos de este...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay algo importante a considerar,

La respuesta .Json puede ser de dos tipos:

**- Si el .json inicia con `{` se considera como objeto Json.**

**- Si el .json inicia con `[` es considerado como Arreglo Json.**

Así que en tu caso obtendrías los objetos json apartir del Arreglo json de esta forma:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(RespuestaJson);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jornada = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    //De esta forma obtendrías los valores del objeto Jornada.
     String idClubLocal = jornada.getString("idClubLocal");
     String idEquipoLocal = jornada.getString("idEquipoLocal");
     String nomLocal = jornada.getString("nomLocal");
     String idClubVisitante = jornada.getString("idClubVisitante");
     String idEquipoVisitante = jornada.getString("idEquipoVisitante");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tiene corchetes significa que es un array, así que debes parsearlo como tal, probablemente antes tenías algo así:

```
JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Ahora tienes que hacer

```
JSONArray raiz = new JSONArray(jsonString);
```

y recorrer el array por cada objeto

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = raiz.getJSONObject(i);
```

luego de eso tu código sigue igual

Comment: Post uno editado. No tengo JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

Comment: En algún punto tienes que estar recibiendo el JSON como string, es ahí donde debes cambiar el código, tal vez te falta incluir esa parte del código

Comment: Acabo de ver tu edición, ¿en donde es que se invoca a la función `parseJson`?

Comment: dentro del try?

Comment: Veo que haz declarado un método `public List<Calendario_Volley> parseJson(JSONObject jsonObject) {`, donde es que llaman a este método?

Comment: Al array list en el archivo Calendario_Volley.class

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38212/discussion-between-rafel-c-f-and-equiso).