# org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, json

Estoy haciendo una consulta a un api que este me regresa la info, pero al querer agregarlo a un listview este me regresa que no se puede convertir...

La estructura que utilizo en el json es

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "ClaveTractor": "xxxx",
      "Placas": "30-EN-5E",
      "Caja": "0",
      "NombreChofer": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "TipoViaje": "LOCALES",
      "Cliete": "SEWS",
      "Coordinador": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "FechaAlta": "2020-09-10T12:11:39.767Z",
      "Celular": "xxxxxxxxx"
    },
    {
      "ClaveTractor": "xxx",
      "Placas": "30-EN-5E",
      "Caja": "LAN73732",
      "NombreChofer": "xxxxx",
      "TipoViaje": "LOCALES",
      "Cliete": "SEWS",
      "Coordinador": "xxxxxxx",
      "FechaAlta": "2020-09-10T09:24:26.970Z",
      "Celular": "xxxxxxxx"
    }
  ]
}
```

ya tengo el controller y el dataset y con este codigo es el que trato de agregarlo

```
JsonArrayRequest billionaireReq = new JsonArrayRequest(path, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt("data"));
                            Iterator<?> keys = jsonObject.keys();

                            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                                String key = (String) keys.next();
                                if (jsonObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {

                                    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get(key);
                                    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                                    dataSet.setCliente(obj.getString("Cliente"));
                                    dataSet.setNombreChofer(obj.getString("NombreChofer"));
                                    dataSet.setCoordinador(obj.getString("Coordinador"));
                                    dataSet.setClaveTractor(obj.getString("ClaveTractor"));
                                    dataSet.setPlaca(obj.getString("Placas"));
                                    dataSet.setCaja(obj.getString("Caja"));
                                    dataSet.setFecha(obj.getString("FechaAlta"));
                                    dataSet.setTipoViaje(obj.getString("TipoViaje"));
                                    dataSet.setNumero(obj.getString("Celular"));

                                    list.add(dataSet);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        adapter.notifyAll();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder add = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        Log.d("error", error.getMessage());
                        add.setMessage(error.getMessage()).setCancelable(true);
                        AlertDialog alert = add.create();
                        alert.setTitle("Error!!");
                        alert.show();
                    }
            });
                Controller.getPermission().addToRequestQueue(billionaireReq);
            }
        });
```

Comment: ¿`Integer.parseInt("data")`? En todo caso está claro que te falla ANTES de esa línea (porque esa instrucción seguro que te lanza un *NumberFormatException*), así que es probable que te falle antes de invocar el código porque Android no puede hacer una conversión.

Comment: Tal vez fue equivocación pero Integer.parseInt("data") es lo que provoca el problema. solo debes usar la llave "data"  : JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("data");

Answer (score 1):

Regla del pulgar:

- Si empieza por `{` es un JSONObject
- Si empieza por `[` es un JSONArray

Lo que tienes es un JSONObject, no un JSONArray. Pero tu quieres que el Listener procese un JSONArray

```
new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
```

Usa un listener que reciba un JSONObject

```
new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
```

, adapta la interface de tu clase

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
```

y modifica tu código de forma adecuada (obten el atributo "data" y parseálo como un JSONArray).

PS: Deberías incluir el stacktrace en tus preguntas, ya tienes experiencia suficiente para saber eso.

De no haber sido porque el `Integer.parseInt("data")` era un error tan evidente que dejaba claro que tu método no se llegaba a ejecutar, no se me habría ocurrido mirar en la definición y probablemente no habría respondido.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta es un `JSONArray` y deseas obtener el `JSONObjet` llamado "data"

```
               @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    try {
                       // JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt("data"));
                      JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("data");
                      ...
                      ...
```

Solo debes obtener el objeto "data" del Array.

Revisa:

[Parser Json volley request](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7439/parser-json-volley-request/7443#7443)