# Error "org.json.JSONException: Value Conexion of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"

Tags: php, java, android, json

Que tal en mi siguiente codigo me esta apareciendo el siguiente error al ejecutarlo la aplicacion ya estaba en etapa de pruebas y habia estado funcionando muy bien pero ahora me arroja el error de que no esta encontrando o recibiendo correctamente el Json me podrian ayudar para saber a que se debe

obtenerUsuarios.php

```
<?php

    require "conexion.php";
    
    // PRUEBAS
    //$usuario = "cheko";
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM empleados,certificaciones WHERE empleado_id = codigo_persona AND Certificacion IN ('Montacargas', 'Picker')";

    $query = $mysqli->query($sql);
    
    $datos = array();

    $fecha_actual = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
    
    while($resultado = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

        $msg="";
        $fecha_final = new DateTime($resultado['Fecha_Ven']);
        $dias = $fecha_actual->diff($fecha_final)->format('%r%a');
        
        // Si la fecha final es igual a la fecha actual o anterior
        if ($dias <=0) {
           $msg="Certificacion Vencida";
        }
        elseif($dias <= 15) {
           $msg="Está a $dias días de vencer";
        }
        else {
           $msg="Certificacion Vigente";
        }
        /*
           Ponemos en $resultado una clave msg
           y en ella el valor de la variable $msg
           En Android, podrás obtener ese valor invocando a msg
           y puedes cambiar msg por como se llame
           el campo destinado a ese dato en tu clase Asociados
        */
        $resultado['msg']=$msg;
        $datos[] = $resultado;
    }
    
    //echo json_encode($datos);
    echo json_encode(array("Usuarios" => $datos));

?>
```

Mi codigo en java es el siguiente pero me muestra el error del json

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ejecutar el php en el navegador si me extrae la informacion pero no me la muestra en la aplicacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de error/trazas de pila en imágenes, publica directamente el texto del código, el texto de los errores y los _stack traces_. Esto hace que sea menos complicado, para quien quiera ayudarte, investigar sobre el tema y hacer sus propias pruebas/adaptaciones al código, al escribir una respuesta y de esa forma aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.

Comment: En alguna parte de tu código se te está escapando esto: `Conexión exitosa`, y eso estaría rompiendo tu JSON. Cuando el cliente espera un JSON en respuesta tú debes controlar tu código de servidor, de modo que sólo salga por pantalla un JSON y nada más. Revisa el archivo `conexion.php`, es posible que allí tengas algo del tipo: `echo "Conexión exitosa";`. Dicho eso, como bien apunta @jachguate, pon siempre el código, mensajes de error, contenido de respuestas del código, etc, **como texto**, nunca como capturas de imagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razòn principal de este error, es que la respuesta que obtienes no es una respuesta json, por ejemplo si el texto "Conexion exitosa" forma parte del json este no se considerìa una respuesta json correcta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recuerda que

**La [respuesta .Json valida, puede ser de dos tipos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7439/parser-json-volley-request/7443#7443):**

- **Si el .json inicia con { se considera como objeto Json.**
- **Si el .json inicia con [ es considerado como Arreglo Json.**

tú mismo puedes validar si esta es un json válido, por ejemplo aquí https://jsonlint.com/.

**Asegura que la respuesta es un .json válido.**

Comment: Muchas gracias si ese conexion exitosa era lo que me estaba ocasionando el problema

Comment: Me da gusto resolvieras el problema @AlbertoCruz , saludos!