# <pre>Array"... is not valid JSON at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: json

Buenas me sale el siguiente error al querer generar un json

VM1174:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "Array"... is not valid JSON at JSON.parse ()at request.onreadystatechange

```
divLoading.style.display = "flex";
            let request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? 
                        new XMLHttpRequest() : 
                        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            let ajaxUrl = BASE_URL+'/Tienda/procesarVenta';
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('direccion',dir);    
            formData.append('ciudad',ciudad);
            formData.append('inttipopago',inttipopago);
            formData.append('nombre',nombre);
            formData.append('apellido',apellido);
            formData.append('dni',dni);
            formData.append('correo',correo);
            formData.append('celular',celular);
            formData.append('domicilio',domicilio);
            formData.append('provincia',provincia);
            request.open("POST",ajaxUrl,true);
            request.send(formData);
            request.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(request.readyState != 4) return;
                if(request.status == 200){
                    let objData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    if(objData.status){
                        window.location = BASE_URL+"/tienda/confirmarpedido/";
                    }else{
                        swal("", objData.msg , "error");
                    }
                }
                divLoading.style.display = "none";
                return false;
            }
```

Salida que obtengo de la ruta del json

```
    Array
    (
        [direccion] => Bueno Aires
        [ciudad] => asda
        [inttipopago] => 3
        [nombre] => sd
        [apellido] => asda
        [dni] => 23
        [correo] => asd
        [celular] => 234
        [domicilio] => wersd
        [provincia] => fdssdf
    )
```

Comment: Imprime el valor de request.responseText y verás que no es un json, ese es el problema.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es simplemente que al tratar de parsear en esta línea, el valor de `responseText` no es en realidad un Json:

```
let objData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
```

Recuerda que **la respuesta .Json válida, puede ser de dos tipos:**

- **Si el .json inicia con `{` se considera como objeto Json.**
- **Si el .json inicia con [ es considerado como Arreglo Json.**

Deberías de tener [una respuesta que inicia con `{` o con `[`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/597913/error-org-json-jsonexception-value-conexion-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be/597939#597939), mientras que de acuerdo al error estás obteniendo una respuesta con un carácter "<":

> VM1174:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "Array"... is not
> valid JSON at JSON.parse ()at request.onreadystatechange

Debes asegurar que el valor de `request.responseText` se en verdad un json de otra forma no podrás parsearla.